# Converts file into HTML but some PHP and JavaScript in the code is not read

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

So I have a page builder here for like the Contact us section. It calls "showcontacts.php" and convert it as a HTML file, but the problem is some of the java scripts doesn't work properly anymore, like the Google Map not shown in mobile view. Is there anyway where in the page builder I won't specify its an html data but both JavaScript, PHP, and HTML or is there any other way that even I convert it into HTML but the JavaScript won't have error?

```
function BuildContacts(){
document.getElementById("menubar_home").className = "nav-link";
document.getElementById("menubar_products").className = "nav-link";
document.getElementById("menubar_careers").className = "nav-link";
document.getElementById("menubar_contacts").className = "nav-link active";
document.getElementById("header_content").innerHTML = "";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "showcontacts.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#header_content').html(data);    
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#header_content').html(textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
        },
    });
});    
}
```

Comment: So you are appending HTML to the page and the JavaScript that is in that html is not running?

Comment: @epascarello In the "showcontacts.php" it has a javascript, html, and php. But in the pagebuilder it makes converts the "showcontacts.php" file into html. Well some of the javascript works but some doesnt. Especially with the google map it doesn't anymore work, i tried it in the mobile view and it doesn't show anymore